# Why would Dr. Strange get upset about Tony Stark leaning on Cauldron of the Cosmos?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Why is Dr. Strange upset about Tony Stark leaning on the Cauldron of the Cosmos when they meet Bruce Banner at the New York Sanctum?

I don’t see any MCU canon regarding it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The Cauldron of the Cosmos is a powerful mystical artifact

> When you are the Sorcerer Supreme of the entire planet, you do not have a whole lot of downtime. Not only that, but when you really let the idea of what your responsibilities are get to you, it can really overwhelm you with just how much there is for you to do. Therefore, a very important function in the life of a Sorcerer Supreme is to have something that can help you relax. Some folks might veg out while watching reality television, but Doctor Strange instead meditates through the Cauldron of the Cosmos, where he can “sit for hours upon end– and dwell upon the immutable mysteries of the universe!”
>
> However, the Cauldron also has **powerful scrying abilities and Doctor Strange can consult with it for information about the universe rather than just for simple meditation**
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.cbr.com/doctor-stranges-15-greatest-magical-artifacts/)</sup>

As for Tony leaning on it..it just shows a lack of respect for Dr Strange's collection. In Tony's defence, ***he's only just met Strange*** and has no idea what the cauldron represents.

Really though, it's just an easter egg reference for comic book aficionados.

> "Here, before the blazing Cauldron of the Cosmos, I oftimes sit for hours upon end-- and dwell upon the immutable mysteries of the universe!"
>
> <sup>Defenders V1 #15 (9/1974)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Isn't that OP asking for MCU reference rather than comic book/outside MCU reference?

Comment: Cauldron doesn’t have much mcu exposure beyond the one scene. Was just wondering what the cauldron is and why it might be dangerous to lean against

Comment: That's true @enorl76